# Jaspersoft Server - Connecting to Microsoft Exchange

Tags: outlook, jasperserver

I setup my Jasper Report Server. As well as I already schedule my reports and every things was working fine with me. During the setup, I was using my personal Gmail accounts to share the emails witch associated with gmail.smtp.com

I changed the SMTP setup to my domain account (Corporate Microsoft Exchange Server) but emails stopped working. I believe there is issue with the SMTP configuration.

Whenever I change the setup to my personal email, everything working fine but when I swap it to my domain account, which is corporate Microsoft Exchange server, it is not working. My domain account Microsoft outlook base, I believe there should not be any issue. Using same credential, I can access from the web.

I check following provided URL from Jasper Community and it seems I am following the same.
URL: https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/configuring-report-scheduler

**What could be the issue?**

Here is the error details, which I got:

```
Subject: The job failed to execute. Review its parameters.
Date: Today
Component: Report Scheduler

Message:
Job: Immediate Execution2323 (ID: 3889) Report unit: /reports/Paid_Violation_of_last_week_ Quartz Job: ReportJobs.job_3889 Quartz Trigger: ReportJobs.trigger_3886_0 Error Message: There was an error on the server. Try again or contact site administrators. (Error UID: 4d89f7cc-28cc-4d1d-86cb-cd0c764e1348).
```

**I would appreciate if someone will share his/her experience if he/she face the same before.**